# Accessing a thread un-safe COMobject in classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, com, iis-7.5

Trying to fix a problem in a classic ASP application, however I am inexperienced. Tried to find more info but was unable to.

The app instantiates a COM object for data retrieval which is not thread-safe, so the following instructions are added.

```
comObject=CreateObject("comServer.comObject")
returnValue=comObject.DoWork(.......)
...
comObject = Nothing
```

However, when processing two different http requests at the same time, the latter one seems to overwrite the first request, giving the first requester an error. It looks as if the comObject variable is shared between the requests.

How to instantiate the object in such a way that every separate request in IIS, gets it's own instance of the comObject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what the object does or how it does it, it's impossible to give specific advice. A general description will have to do:

The object is broken/buggy. It is the object's responsibility to handle the problem.

A COM object is supposed to handle all threading issues internally, or defer to COM STA apartments if it cannot do it, or doesn't want to (for those aspects that an STA can handle). This goes deep into the design of the object.

Regardless of COM Apartment choice, a DoWork(...) method with a semantic that precludes multiple separate COM objects in separate threads from handling simultaneous calls - is a seriously problematic design at best. A proper design would either include mechanisms to handle the conflict explicitly, or just hide the conflict from the calling code and handle the conflict internally.

Depending on the details of what DoWork() does, there might be ways to fix the object in such a way that the calls can succeed in parallel, or block each other so the calls are effectively serialized, or to cause the second call to throw a "You already called me" error. Again, which approach is more appropriate depends heavily on what the method does.

If you can't modify this broken component, your best option would be to write a COM wrapper that ensures serialization to the real object.

In any case, there is nothing reasonable you can do from the client (ASP VBScript) side.